# Entity Framework 6 left outer join

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

I have a query where I am trying to get a queue of driver work, and I need the query to return, at the very least, the list of drivers (with, or without, queued work).  One driver can have many, or no, driver queue records.  The below code is returning 0 items.

```
 var queues = db.DriverQueues.AsNoTracking().Join(db.Drivers
                                                , z => z.DriverID   //FK
                                                , y => y.DriverID   //PK
                                                , (y, z) => new
                                                {
                                                    Driver = z,
                                                    DriverQueue = y
                                                })
                                        .OrderBy(y => y.Driver.DriverID)
                                        .ThenBy(z => z.DriverQueue.IntermodalWorkID).ToList();
```

Also, the DriverQueue table currently has no records so I should be getting just a list of the drivers with no records back.

Comment: Why can't you do `db.Driver.Include(d => d.Queue)`? If not, fix that. It is rare that you should EVER use the `Join` in Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1):

If you have collection of `DriverQueue` on `Driver`, you can use `SelectMany` and `DefaultIfEmpty`.

```
public ICollection<DriverQueue> DriverQueues { get; set; }
```

Code:

```
var queues = db.Drivers.AsNoTracking()
    .SelectMany(d => d.DriverQueues
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
        .Select(q => new { Driver = d, DriverQueue = q }))
    .OrderBy(d => d.Driver.DriverID)
    .ThenBy(q => q.DriverQueue.IntermodalWorkID)
    .ToList();
```

If not, you can use `GroupJoin`, `DefaultIfEmpty` and `SelectMany` to achieve that.

```
var queues = db.Drivers.AsNoTracking()
    .GroupJoin(
        db.DriverQueues,
        d => d.DriverID, // PK
        q => q.DriverID, // FK
        (d, qs) => qs
            .DefaultIfEmpty()
            .Select(q => new { Driver = d, DriverQueue = q }))
    .SelectMany(g => g)
    .OrderBy(d => d.Driver.DriverID)
    .ThenBy(q => q.DriverQueue.IntermodalWorkID)
    .ToList();
```